# Node.js Osmosis Repeating Results

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using [Osmosis](https://github.com/rc0x03/node-osmosis) for scraping .

Here is the example i wrote for scraping Bing search result
:

```
var osmosis = require('node-osmosis');

var keyword = "download game"

osmosis.get('http://www.bing.com/search?q='+keyword) // url of the site you want to scrape  
  .find('//*[@id="b_results"]/li/div[2]/p') // selector
  .set('info') // name of the key in the results
  .find('//*[@id="b_results"]/li/div[1]/h2')
  .set('title')
  .find('//*[@id="b_results"]/li/div[1]/h2/a/@href')
  .set('link')
  .data(function(results) { //output
    console.log(results);
  });
```

The Problem i have , when i run this code its repeat result for each item (10 time!).

somethin like this :

```
{  title: 'GameHouse - Official Site',
  link: 'http://www.gametop.com/' }
{ info: 'Searching for safe and virus-free Game Downloads to play? Our site is packed with downloadable games in a variety of genres, download the Free Versions and have …',
  title: 'GameHouse - Official Site',
  link: 'http://www.download-free-games.com/' }
{ info: 'Searching for safe and virus-free Game Downloads to play? Our site is packed with downloadable games in a variety of genres, download the Free Versions and have …',
  title: 'GameHouse - Official Site',
  link: 'http://www.myplaycity.com/' }
{ info: 'Searching for safe and virus-free Game Downloads to play? Our site is packed with downloadable games in a variety of genres, download the Free Versions and have …',
  title: 'GameHouse - Official Site',
  link: 'http://download.cnet.com/windows/games/' }
{ info: 'Searching for safe and virus-free Game Downloads to play? Our site is packed with downloadable games in a variety of genres, download the Free Versions and have …',
  title: 'GameHouse - Official Site',
  link: 'http://www.gametop.com/category/downloadable.html' }
{ info: 'Searching for safe and virus-free Game Downloads to play? Our site is packed with downloadable games in a variety of genres, download the Free Versions and have …',
  title: 'GameHouse - Official Site',
  link: 'http://www.shockwave.com/download.jsp' }
{ info: 'Searching for safe and virus-free Game Downloads to play? Our site is packed with downloadable games in a variety of genres, download the Free Versions and have …',
  title: 'GameHouse - Official Site',
  link: 'http://www.myplaycity.com/games/' }
{ info: 'Searching for safe and virus-free Game Downloads to play? Our site is packed with downloadable games in a variety of genres, download the Free Versions and have …',
  title: 'GameHouse - Official Site',
  link: 'https://www.games.com/' }
{ info: 'Searching for safe and virus-free Game Downloads to play? Our site is packed with downloadable games in a variety of genres, download the Free Versions and have …',
  title: 'GameHouse - Official Site',
  link: 'https://www.gamehouse.com/' }
{ info: 'Searching for safe and virus-free Game Downloads to play? Our site is packed with downloadable games in a variety of genres, download the Free Versions and have …',
  title: 'GameHouse - Official Site',
  link: 'http://www.games2download.com/' }
{ info: 'Searching for safe and virus-free Game Downloads to play? Our site is packed with downloadable games in a variety of genres, download the Free Versions and have …',
  title: 'Games 2 Download - 1000 virus-free …',
  link: 'http://www.gametop.com/' }
{ info: 'Searching for safe and virus-free Game Downloads to play? Our site is packed with downloadable games in a variety of genres, download the Free Versions and have …',
  title: 'Games 2 Download - 1000 virus-free …',
  link: 'http://www.download-free-games.com/' }
{ info: 'Searching for safe and virus-free Game Downloads to play? Our site is packed with downloadable games in a variety of genres, download the Free Versions and have …',
  title: 'Games 2 Download - 1000 virus-free …',
  link: 'http://www.myplaycity.com/' }
{ info: 'Searching for safe and virus-free Game Downloads to play? Our site is packed with downloadable games in a variety of genres, download the Free Versions and have …',
  title: 'Games 2 Download - 1000 virus-free …',
  link: 'http://download.cnet.com/windows/games/' }
{ info: 'Searching for safe and virus-free Game Downloads to play? Our site is packed with downloadable games in a variety of genres, download the Free Versions and have …',
  title: 'Games 2 Download - 1000 virus-free …',
  link: 'http://www.gametop.com/category/downloadable.html' }
{ info: 'Searching for safe and virus-free Game Downloads to play? Our site is packed with downloadable games in a variety of genres, download the Free Versions and have …',
  title: 'Games 2 Download - 1000 virus-free …',
  link: 'http://www.shockwave.com/download.jsp' }
{ info: 'Searching for safe and virus-free Game Downloads to play? Our site is packed with downloadable games in a variety of genres, download the Free Versions and have …',
  title: 'Games 2 Download - 1000 virus-free …',
  link: 'http://www.myplaycity.com/games/' }
{ info: 'Searching for safe and virus-free Game Downloads to play? Our site is packed with downloadable games in a variety of genres, download the Free Versions and have …',
  title: 'Games 2 Download - 1000 virus-free …',
  link: 'https://www.games.com/' }
{ info: 'Searching for safe and virus-free Game Downloads to play? Our site is packed with downloadable games in a variety of genres, download the Free Versions and have …',
  title: 'Games 2 Download - 1000 virus-free …',
  link: 'https://www.gamehouse.com/' }
{ info: 'Searching for safe and virus-free Game Downloads to play? Our site is packed with downloadable games in a variety of genres, download the Free Versions and have …',
  title: 'Games 2 Download - 1000 virus-free …',
  link: 'http://www.games2download.com/' }
```

I wants know how can fix this .thanks

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but my guess is it multiplies number of occurrence when you find an element.

let say you have 2 elements to set. First element `.find(element1)` and it found 3 matches. and the second element `.find(element2)` found 2 matches.

the number of rows you will get is 6.